# Run ASP.NET project outside of visual studio

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, command-line, iis-express

I have an ASP.NET project in visual studio which works with IIS Express. I want to build and run the project in the browser without opening visual studio. Is it possible? Remember that I don't want to deploy it to IIS.

EDIT:
I corrected my command based on the provided answers. This is my command:

```
@ECHO off
SET CurrentDir="%CD%"
SET IISRoot="%ProgramFiles(x86)%\IIS Express\"
CD /D %IISRoot%
START http://localhost:7710/
IISExpress /path:%CurrentDir%\ProjectFolder\ /port:7710
```

Comment: So you want to run IIS Express to access the web-application project?

Comment: Yes, I want to run the application but don't need to debug it inside visual studio. Loading process is time consuming.

Comment: [this](http://weblogs.asp.net/wenching/archive/2008/07/24/running-asp-net-2-0-on-filesystem-instead-of-iis-without-visual-studio-2005-2008-installed.aspx) may help you.

Comment: jomsk1e's link is good. If it's an ASP.NET 4.0 site you will need to run WebDev.WebServer40.exe instead of WebServer20

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Of couse you can. To build it just run

```
 C:\ Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\MSbuild.exe
```

If you use different version of framework just check the correct path

To run it call

```
  iisexpress /path:c:\myapp\ /port:9090
```

Comment: Thanks to other respondents, but I can't locate the files they mentioned. Anyhow, this location worked for me. This is the correct command that worked for me. (In The Following Comments.)

Comment: set root="%ProgramFiles(x86)%\IIS Express\"

Comment: CD /D %rootdirectory%

Comment: iisexpress.exe /path:C:\ProjectFolder\ /port:7710

Comment: I wished Garath could edit his answer, since I'm not allowed to do that. :)