# How to run asp.net project on localhost:xxxx without Visual studio?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, iis, devexpress

I recently installed [DevExpress](https://www.devexpress.com/) on my machine, when running it's demos

[image: DevExpress demo]

I found that the it was able to run the project on http://localhost:xxxx.

My question is:

What DevExpress is doing behind the scenes to run a project on localhost without Visual studio?

I found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23622613/2404470), however it only clarifies how can the project "run" **manually** without Visual Studio. DevExpress is programmatically running the demo project without my manual help.

Any idea? Kind folks?

Comment: Self hosting a web app is not magic. You can use either a server such as IIS Express, or simply write your own server based on HTTP API. Not sure what DevExpress chooses but it is feasible.

Comment: @LexLi I believe that they uses IIS Express only. Say, if you're supposed to use IIS Express, how will you do it programmatically?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Run ASP.NET project outside of Visual Studio](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23622613/run-asp-net-project-outside-of-visual-studio?lq=1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider running the below command

`iisexpress /path:c:\myapp\ /port:9090`

Comment: Maybe by using `Application.SendKeys`?